# Intercept every click in document via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to inject a code into several pages that will handle clicks on specific elements within the document.
I succeeded doing this via jQuery.

The problem is that jQuery isn't available on all pages. So it works only half the times. I want to check the `href` attribute of every `<a>` that I click. Anyone got an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You want to add an event listener to the document, which is in effect what jQuery was doing for you.

Check out the MDN documentation on adding event listeners:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Your result should be something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', yourFunction, false);
```

This works in IE9+ and all other browsers. To support IE8 and below use attachEvent instead:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', yourFunction, false);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('click', yourFunction, false);
}
```

Your function will now be passed an Event Object which will have a property called 'target', which is the node that was clicked. You can read more about that on MDN, too:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event

Again, that's only in IE9+ and standards browsers. In IE7 and IE8 the event object is a property of the window object... but that's the subject of another question if your sleuthing on google doesn't turn up some results.

This is basically what jQuery does behind the scenes. I suggest that reading jQuery's source code can teach you an awful lot of tricks like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could inject jQuery into the page and then proceed as normal.

You'd do this through your browser's JS console.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery doesn't do anything you couldn't do yourself with "plain" javascript. You can easily do a `document.getElementsByName('a')` , and loop over the results to attach your on-click handler.

Comment: An arguably more robust solution would be attaching the event to `document` and checking `event.target.href`.

Answer (score 0):

For attaching an EventListener on every link, and retrieving the href on click without jQuery, I would probably do something like this:

```
function trackClick(event) {
    alert(this.href);
}


window.onload = function() {

    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', trackClick, false);
    };

}
```

Comment: As you might see already, as @stephband has already pointed out above here – < IE9 does not support addEventListener, and for them you have to use attachEvent.